# Query in php - telling system what to do if no data is available

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query checking some data in a table (name and a number associated with it) and returning one of them I need to set as a variable.

However, I run into trouble when I need to consider items that are not yet in the table - newcomers - as they should be regarded as having 0 as data but very obviously they do not have it in the database.

The script is as follows:

```
        $jQuery = mysql_query("SELECT team, points FROM DCO_standings_teams WHERE competition='1' AND team='$teamname' AND year='$lastyear'");
{
    $points="$row[1]";
    $pointsmult = $points*50;
    $pointsoffer = $wage_offer/100;
    $bid_total = $pointsoffer+$pointsmult+$loyaltybonus;
}
```

In this case, say that Team A had 12 points from last year. It would set "12" as $points and go on to do all the other calculations.

What I need is something to tell the site that, IF no record is found in the DCO_standings_teams table, then it should set $points as 0.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Where did you get that `$row` variable?

Comment: Why did you downvote everyone? Because nobody did your work for you? I think that everyone offered a fair solution.

Comment: I swear I didn't downvote anyone? (including my own post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT team, points FROM DCO_standings_teams WHERE competition='1' AND team='{$teamname}' AND year='{$lastyear}'");

if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
  $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
  $points = $row[1];
}
else {
  $points = 0;
}

$pointsmult = $points*50;
$pointsoffer = $wage_offer/100;
$bid_total = $pointsoffer+$pointsmult+$loyaltybonus;
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much!

To answer some of the other comments - I am working on "legacy" code to make it work while a new one and (I would hope) complying to the new standards is made (which could take months).
By counting the results, as above, I was able to set the condition for an if/else for the $points variable.

Answer (score 0):

You did that already...

```
if($points === null){
    $points = 0;
}
```

---

Side point:

`$points="$row[1]";` makes no sense.... just do: `$points = $row[1];`

Answer (score 0):

I would cast the value to an integer.   Like so:

```
$points = (int) $row[1];
```

Comment: Apparently some people object to casting integers as integers?

Answer (score 0):

let's think about what you're doing for a second:

When you query your database, you're given results. If you have no results, then you must have a 'newcomer' as you say.

So, let's count the number of 'points' before we continue the code, no?

As others will allude to, you should be using a different function other than mysql_*, but that's not my concern here.

```
$jQuery = mysql_query("SELECT team, points FROM DCO_standings_teams WHERE competition='1' AND team='$teamname' AND year='$lastyear'");
$points = $row[1];
if($points == null) { // if there are no points (not 0, because that means there are 0 points)
     die("You are a newcomer."); 
     // do newcomer logic here 
} elseif($points > 0) { 
     //do other logic here
}
```